# Rendering Parameterized Function Results

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that I am using to check if there are results from a page load and if there are, then map the array and return a component and if there aren't then return a string stating there are no results. At the moment I have been able to write the function without any issue, but I can't seem to get return statement to load. Am I following the right path to returning the components or is there a better method?

The console logs return the correct info, but everything in the `return()` isn't appearing in the view.

```
export default class BlogKanbanLayout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.resultsCheck = this.resultsCheck.bind(this);
    }

    resultsCheck(blogs, user) {
        console.log("resultsCheck")
        console.log(blogs)
        console.log(blogs.length)

        if(blogs.length === 0) {
            <p>There are no results for your filter criteria.</p>
        } else {
            console.log("There are blog results")
            console.log(blogs)
            console.log(user)
                blogs.map((blog, index) => {
                    console.log("blog map")
                    console.log(blog)
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <p>This is a test></p>
                            <BlogKanbanCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={user} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-12">
                {this.resultsCheck(this.props.negativeBlogs, this.props.user)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `resultsCheck` you forgot to return the result of your mapping.
Also, the key used in the map function needs to be given to parent element, which here is your `div`.
And using conditional rendering you can reduce your entire component to the following code for te exact same result :

```
export default class BlogKanbanLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { negativeBlogs, user } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="col-md-12">
                {negativeBlogs.length ?
                    negativeBlogs.map(blog => 
                        <div className="row" key={blog.blogIdHash}>
                            <p>This is a test></p>
                            <BlogKanbanCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={user} />
                        </div>
                    )
                    :
                    <p>There are no results for your filter criteria.</p>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And since you are not using the state of your component you could even optimize it to a stateless one :

```
const BlogKanbanLayout = ({ negativeBlogs, user }) =>
    <div className="col-md-12">
        {negativeBlogs.length ?
            negativeBlogs.map(blog => 
                <div className="row" key={blog.blogIdHash}>
                    <p>This is a test></p>
                    <BlogKanbanCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={user} />
                </div>
            )
            :
            <p>There are no results for your filter criteria.</p>
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You `resultsCheck` method need to return something, so you need to add the `return` statement before the two results

```js
    resultsCheck(blogs, user) {
        console.log("resultsCheck")
        console.log(blogs)
        console.log(blogs.length)

        if(blogs.length === 0) {
            return <p>There are no results for your filter criteria.</p>
        } else {
            console.log("There are blog results")
            console.log(blogs)
            console.log(user)
            return blogs.map((blog, index) => {
                    console.log("blog map")
                    console.log(blog)
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <p>This is a test></p>
                            <BlogKanbanCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={user} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
        }
    }
```